# Feasible FIRE setup?

Tags: starting-out-investing, financial-independence

Wondering about FIRE, in case you do not have family, rent or any other bigger expenses how much should you have to start FIRE (multiply of month or year costs) ?

*Also rest of capital could be consumed at the end. Suppose average long term 10% p.a. out of stocks and reasonable inflation.*

Comment: Apart from the subjective risk tolerance issue highlighted below, you need to consider what *other* financial goals you have. A high risk portfolio might make sense for a 30-year term to retirement, but makes way way less sense when saving money for, eg., a house. Also consider costs for kids (now or planned), medical contingencies, etc etc etc

Answer (score 5):

FIRE is largely about how much risk you are willing to accept. The 1st 2 bullet points, to me, are wildly optimistic. The market has always, always had good years and bad years. Just in the last 2 decades, you have the '08 housing bubble crash and the Great Recession and then the global pandemic. Each of those would have at least temporarily put a very hefty dent in those 1st two bullet points.

And then 1 yr of cash in a savings account would not have been enough to wait for the securities in the 1st 2 points to come back. If the high risk one would have come back at all.

To me, seems very risky and very optimistic. I would not call this 'a good idea'. But as I opened with, if you want to accept that risk, that's your choice.

Comment: Thank you, me I do not mind "risks" and it is very hard to get any new longer term job in EU with IT background, 49+, not white, foreign name. And it is quite worthless spending an year to find new job and get fired after 8 month for example - will try to find something more stable to have also paid insurance and another income to keep valuable investments untouched :-)

Comment: @Jan Not to be rude, but if you're 49+, you're really straining the "E" part of "FIRE". Advice regarding putting several years of income into high-risk investment is not going to the same for a 25-year-old versus a 50-year-old.

Comment: I know, I am doing wrong, but when it is hard to get any work and you do not want to worry :-) Also got result adventurer(?) here https://www.16personalities.com/ so it is inline with my personality. Mind already lost almost half of savings in single fund once. If you have to, you have to (advert.) and everyone repeats same mistakes again and again...

Answer (score 2):

### ~6% Real Rate of Return

If there was a way of getting 25% annual return on your money, **everyone** would do it.

There's not.

You're going to get something like 10% - which after taxes and inflation is going to be something like 6% real rate of return.

So do a low cost index fund or ETF, and accept that you're going to get ~6% ROI.

### FIRE is about Costs

I've always understood FIRE to be about controlling costs. If you lower your expenses there are two benefits:

1. More money to Invest
2. Less money needed for retirement

The first is obvious, if you have some fixed income and you spend less of it, there's more left over for investing.

The second point is more subtle. Your retirement nest egg is directly proportional to your expected expenses. If you lower your expenses by 20% (say by moving to a smaller house or paying off a mortgage early) then then your "number" - the amount you need to have to retire - **also goes down by 20%.**

FIRE is about aggressively cutting non-essential costs, so that you're only spending money on things that truly make you happy. This helps you to save more quickly until you have enough invested to cover your expenses. (generally the nest egg is ~25x the annual expenses.)

Comment: Thank you, but you are probably wrong. It is quite easy to get 1,5-2% per month by leveraged speculations (short term risky trades 2%/20*12 => 1.2% p.a. without leverage would be funny profit) and 10% p.a. should be long term average of major indices. And in our country you have to pay only 15% tax and fixed health insurance from trading income.

Comment: "10% p.a. should be long term average of major indices" -- correct. And you will not be able to *consistently* beat that average. (that's why it's the average)

Comment: "And in our country you have to pay only 15% tax[...] from trading income" -- Which is very close to the US 20% tax on trading income. Start with 10% return, subtract 2% for inflation, and 1.5% for tax on profits, and you're at 6.5% annual real rate of return. **Again, if it is feasible to do better than that, everyone would!**

Comment: Right, anyway not counting inflation - may still spent part of capital later too. There are few funds beating even in US and looking forward with optimism :-), even waiting invested without spending all returns for some time can improve predicted future for a bit. Geting 25 yr. expenses could take too long for one life :-)